# How do I manage my generated Link Labels?

Tags: c#

I've generated a list of Link Labels using some code but I don't know how to make it do something when you click on the LinkLabel if they doesn't exist yet till my code has run.
Here is my code

```
        var n = File.ReadLines(HorseFile).Count();

        var HC = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            string HorseName = File.ReadLines(HorseFile).ElementAtOrDefault(HC);
            LinkLabel HorseLabel = new LinkLabel();
            HorseLabel.Left = 35;
            HorseLabel.Top = (i + 4) * 21;
            HorseLabel.Text = String.Format(HorseName, HC);
            this.Controls.Add(HorseLabel);

            HC++;
        }
```

...it produces the list from a text file created earlier in the code as Link Labels so to start with so I know it works I want it to do something like MessageBox.Show(); with the contents of the link label shown. How do I do this? Can anybody give me an example?

Comment: Attach an event handler to the `Click` event.

Comment: The link label doesn't exist tho till i've run my code so i'm a little lost on where to go next, my Form is blank at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Alejandro in the comments, wire up the [LinkClicked()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your LinkLabel:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HorseFile = @"C:\Users\mikes\Documents\SomeFile.txt";

        int count = 0;
        foreach(string HorseName in File.ReadLines(HorseFile))
        {
            LinkLabel HorseLabel = new LinkLabel();
            HorseLabel.Left = 35;
            HorseLabel.Top = (count + 4) * 21;
            HorseLabel.Text = HorseName;

            HorseLabel.LinkClicked += HorseLabel_LinkClicked; // wire up the event

            this.Controls.Add(HorseLabel);
            count++;
        }
    }

    private void HorseLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkLabel Horse = (LinkLabel)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(Horse.Text);
    }
```